# Mixing dialogue and action tags

Tags: creative-writing

In my case, I never use dialogue and action tags in the same unit of dialogue (sorry, I just call them **units** because I had no idea what they are called).

So I would never write something like this:

> **Jane heaved a sigh, finally giving up. Then she raised her eyes with a
>   warm smile.** “It's nothing, Dad," **she said.** "I'm just a little worn
>   out. That's all.”

I think I read somewhere (I don't remember where) that it's unnecessary since I  already have an action tag at the beginning (so it's clear who is saying the line.)

Still, I've seen writers adding the *he said/she said* after having used an action tag. I'm not very sure why they do it. I guess to make the piece flow better or add a *small pause*?

Is it usually better to not to mix dialogue and action tags in the same "dialogue unit?" If not, what are the situations you would like to do so?

Comment: OT, but in your sample above, it should be "Dad" not "dad," since "Dad" is being used as a proper noun.  Example: My dad is great.  Example: I love you, Dad.  (I mention this because you've said before that you're not a native English speaker, and you want to improve your English writing.  Not trying to be the grammar police.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's about rhythm. Putting *she said* gives readers a tiny pause as they read that bit of dialogue. Sometimes people call that small pause a *beat.*

An alternative is to insert a small action instead of *she said.* But *she said* works nicely if you don't want a new action in there.

You can also rearrange the sentence to so that you get a beat without adding either *she said* or a new action:

> Jane heaved a sigh, finally giving up. “It's nothing, dad." She raised her eyes with a warm smile. "I'm just a little worn out. That's all.”

So play around with the possibilities. For me, the choice often comes down to rhythm, pacing, and the sound of how the sentences flow.